# How to transpose a table with a variable but limited number of matching entries

Tags: sql, db2

I am working with the following table DDL:

```
 CREATE TABLE foo (
   globalkey INTEGER NOT NULL,   
   subkey INTEGER NOT NULL,   
   type VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,   
   bar VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL 
  );
```

The table contains records of different type (e.g. "t1", "t2" and "t3"). The primary key of the table is (globalkey, subkey). For each globalkey there can be 1-n records some of them may share the same type. However there are only 0-3 number of records with type "t1".

I'd like to create a query that gives me all globalkeys that have at least one record with type "t1" and returns the 3 bar values as 3 different columns in the result.

So for the given data:

```
GLOBALKEY, SUBKEY, TYPE, BAR
1          1     t1     hit1
1          28    t1     hit1234
1          315   t2     miss
1          967   t1     hit4711
2          1     t5     miss
2          13    t5     miss
2          18    t1     hit9876
3          1     t2     miss
```

I'd like to get:

```
GLOBALKEY, BAR1,   BAR2,   BAR3
1,         "hit1", "hit1234", "hit4711"
3,         "hit9876",  NULL , NULL
```

I created a SQLFiddle under: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04855

I'd greatly appreciate any pointer on how to get this done!

Bye,

Markus

UPDATE #1: I did not make it clear enough in my initial version that the column BAR contains any arbitrary values, so I can't use the exact version of @Mita statement as this assumes that the values in the case statements are fixed ('hit1', 'hit2', ...). However in the meantime I found out how this problem can be overcome by using the row_number() window function. Check out my edit of @Mita's answer. Updated the SQLFiddle accourdingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSFiddle inserts are not with the data you gave in the example. The correct data should be:

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,1,'t1','hit1');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,28,'t1','hit2');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,315,'t2','miss');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1,967,'t1','hit3');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2,1,'t5','miss');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2,13,'t5','miss');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2,18,'t1','hit1');
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (3,1,'t2','miss');
```

And the query (if I understood you right) should be:

```
SELECT
    globalkey,
    MAX(CASE WHEN bar = 'hit1' THEN 'hit1' ELSE NULL END) AS bar1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN bar = 'hit2' THEN 'hit2' ELSE NULL END) AS bar2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN bar = 'hit3' THEN 'hit3' ELSE NULL END) AS bar3
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    type = 't1'
GROUP BY
    globalkey
```

Comment: Mita's query assumes that 'hit1', 'hit2',... are fixed values. In my example they are not enumerated but could be any text. Check out what I've found out in the meantime in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE #1: Mita's query assumes that 'hit1', 'hit2',... are fixed values. In my example they are not enumerated but could be any text. By using window functions you can however achieve what I was looking for. First select all matching rows (type='t1') and add a new column containg the row-number within the current globalkey.

Using this intermediary result set one can then transpose the table similiar to @MITA's answer.

So in DB2 you can do:

```
WITH tmp1 AS (SELECT globalkey, bar, row_number() OVER (partition by globalkey) AS rnr
WHERE  
    type='t1'
)

SELECT globalkey,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnr = 1 THEN bar ELSE NULL END) AS bar1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnr = 2 THEN bar ELSE NULL END) AS bar2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rnr = 3 THEN bar ELSE NULL END) AS bar3
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    type = 't1'
GROUP BY
    globalkey
```

Comment: They were fixed before the main question was edited. In your suggestion they are not fixed, but you assume you have only 3 distinct values. Otherwise you will not get results for the next

Comment: @Mita Sorry I only found out after I've read your answer that the original data I posted created the impression of fixed data. Nevertheless thanks for taking time to answer the question!